# ring an alarm even in silent mode when sms keyword is received for android

Tags: android, sms, alarm

What does alarmmanager really do? Is it the one that really plays the sound or just some kind of trigger? I'm trying to make an application that will play an alarm even in silent mode when received a sms with a certain keyword, then display an alert dialog that will provide the user with buttons to press to reply to the message. I've been studying and finding working examples online for about a week but none of them even play the alarm. plus, the examples are always different and confusing that just gets me more frustrated. I'm a newbie in android app dev. please help me.. thanks in advance. here is my code

```
public class EAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String sender;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) 
    { 
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) 
            pdusObj[i]); 
            sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    } 

    for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("alert")) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ReceiverInterface.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                12345, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);
        }//end if
    }//end for

}// end onreceive
}
```

I'm sorry if the code was really messy

```
public class ReceiverInterface extends Activity{
final Context context = this;
String my_password = "1234";
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receiverinterface);

   alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Emergency signal received");

            alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click availability status")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("available",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dispatch_available_action();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("not available",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

}// end oncreate()


public void dispatch_available_action(){
    final EditText password_input = new EditText(this); // create an text input field
    password_input.setHint("Enter Password"); // put a hint in it
    password_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD); // change it to password type

    alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new Builder(this); // create an alert box
    alertDialog.setTitle("Enter Password"); // set the title
    alertDialog.setView(password_input);  // insert the password text field in the alert box
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'OK' button
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             String entered_password = password_input.getText().toString();
             if (entered_password.equals(my_password)) {
                 alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Send status");

                 alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                 alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            try {

                            String message = "available";
                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            EAlarmReceiver eReceiver = new EAlarmReceiver();
                            String eSender = eReceiver.sender;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eSender,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage(eSender, null, message, null, null);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "SMS failed, please try again later!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                      });
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();

             } else {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Wrong password!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        } 
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'Cancel' button
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        } 
    });
    alertDialog.show(); // show the alert box
}
}
```

The alertdialog is working fine, I just can't get the alarm to ring, let alone do it while in silent mode.

Comment: To ring a device when sms with a specific keyword is received Visit <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720965/perfom-an-action-on-getting-specific-text-in-sms-in-android/23788111#23788111>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perfom an action on getting specific text in SMS in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720965/perfom-an-action-on-getting-specific-text-in-sms-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) does is execute a PendingIntent at a given time, with an optional repeat. It has nothing to do with audio streams. [This howto](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#sound_overview) will probably help you play a sound when your PendingIntent is received.